# Advisor writing bulk/entire student thesis

Tags: thesis, advisor, ethics

I am forced to write this question as I believe it is unethical and needs to be addressed in my faculty. I suspect a faculty member in my university has the habit of writing his students' masters thesis (for free or for a fee). I believe he does it for a fee. A colleague has mentioned this before, but that colleague isn't a board member so I can't really take his word officially.

I noticed that for several theses I examined for the examination board, his students have a very solid thesis but performed questionable during oral presentations. Some colleagues think it's stage fright, but I believe it is more than that.

This faculty member always requests that corrections for the thesis be mailed to him to "pass to his student". I think he's just doing the corrections and submitting the final copy. This faculty member taught me in my undergraduate years in the same faculty and I heard some stories of his shady dealings with students then.

**Question:** How can something like this be investigated since there are no mechanisms in place to limit what a supervisor contributes to their students' thesis? It is difficult to get the students to testify as this is what most of them would want by default.

Comment: I think there is little to do. The most important thing to me is that s/he does not get profits (others than having all students attaining the degree).

Comment: I believe he does that for a fee. A colleague has mentioned this before but that colleague isn't a board member so I can't really take his word officially.

Comment: " very solid thesis but would have you questioning their abilities during oral presentations."  That is not unusual.

Comment: Its completely normal for student to perform less well at viva than on paper (and vice versa). Insisting that the examiners pass corrects to the faculty member to pass on to the student does strike me as irregular though.

Comment: @IanSudbery Or thorough: Perhaps the supervisor wants to make sure corrections are made.

Comment: I'm not saying its not possible that there are good reasons. it would just be very unusual. In fact, the supervisor getting highly involved in a master's like that would be seen as unfair on those whose supervisors do not get so involved. That's clearly true, and unavoidable for PhDs, but masters are generally seen a little different, and often there are processes in place to ensure that every student gets the same amount of help.

Comment: @IanSudbery, at my univ, in math, in the U.S., there are absolutely no procedures in place to ensure that Master's (or PhD's) get "the same amount of help". In some cases this does mean that students are effectively marooned.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158419/advisor-writing-bulk-entire-student-thesis https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/158419/advisor-writing-bulk-entire-student-thesis

Answer (score 2):

Contact the University Thesis Office regarding policies regarding professors making edits. Maybe what he is doing is sanctioned; maybe there is a strict policy against it. The prof. won't tell you, and the college won't shake the boat. University administration offers the only chance of independent administration.

Comment: How could bribery possibly be sanctioned?

Comment: What bribery? It's not like the professor is being paid to pass them. Regardless, the whole point of having an oral exam board is to prevent exactly that, by having reps from college and university present to ensure that the candidate is of sufficient quality.

Comment: It's in the question: "I believe he does that for a fee."

Comment: There is a lot of supposition and hearsay in the question, regarding whether the activity in question has happened, and to what degree it has happened. The degree to which the university regards professorial participation in thesis writing as unacceptable is also unknown. Finally, the question regards how to get something investigated, not whether a crime is sanctioned.

Comment: Your answer implies a crime might be allowed.  That is wrong.

Comment: My answer implies that many things the author considers to be criminal may not be considered criminal by the professor, the department, the college, or the university.

Comment: Anyone who considers bribery to be a crime will consider your answer to be wrong, then.

Comment: If people who accept assertions on the basis of hearsay consider my answer to be wrong, I can live with that.

Comment: Now it sounds like you are assuming the question is wrong, which is not a reasonable approach to answering questions.  There is nothing about hearsay here; the asker wants to know how to gather evidence of a crime.

Comment: @Mox It my seem like hearsay at this point which is why I asked for a way to investigate this. Note that it is difficult to get a student to testify as he does not force them to take this deals. Most of our masters students work in the industry and some  would generally prefer this option when it is presented to them as they won't have to "stress" themselves.

Comment: @Mox Here's another reason I believe he does that apart from what I heard from a colleague. I got a call from a strange number telling me this colleague gave him my contact. That he is enrolled for a PhD in XXX in another university and would like for me to help him with his research. I told him I am available to assist if he has questions. He went ahead to make it clear that he wants me to write the whole thesis and tell him the price. I told him I can't do that but again available to answer his technical questions. ..

Comment: Weeks later, I ran into this colleague outside school and he asked if someone called me, I told him what our conversation was about and how I turned him down. He said it's a shame because the man is rich and is willing to pay any amount. That he would have done it if it was in his core area. This isn't hearsay. This was a conversation between the both of us.

Answer (score 0):

> How can something like this be investigated since there are no mechanism in place to limit what a supervisor contributes to his students' thesis?

I doubt it is true that there are no mechanisms for this.  Academics are generally bound by broad ethics rules in relation to their research and supervision, and this would almost certainly fall within the scope of those rules.  Being paid a separate fee to write the entire thesis for the student is something that would obviously fall well beyond what is appropriate help for a student, and it would almost certainly be a breach of research ethics.  A complaint of this matter could be raised either with the Head of Department for the faculty the academic is in (or was in at the time of the alleged conduct) or with the university Research Committee or Higher-Degree Committee.

As far as the actual investigative aspects are concerned, that is where it gets trickier, but not impossible.  The university might interview past students or look through correspondence between the students and the academic.  The university has the power to open investigations into the past award of a degree (and withdraw it under appropriate circumstances) and so this can be used as a way of seeking responses from past students.  The university also has access to all emails, etc., on their own systems, and there is generally no right of the academic to privacy of these things beyond certain narrow bounds (e.g., personal emails that do not relate to work).  In a complaint proceeding, the university would certainly give this academic an opportunity to tell them what he has been doing, and give his own arguments in relation to his practices.  He might even admit it, and argue that what he does is okay, in which case evidentiary issues would be moot.

Comment: What if the professor and the students used their private e-mail accounts? How do you investigate it?

Answer (score -5):

Just like any other situation where bribery is suspected, a sting operation can be used by law enforcement to get proof.

1. Find someone who could plausibly offer a bribe.
2. Give them immunity to punishment.
3. Have them offer a bribe.
4. If the bribe is accepted, you have proof.

You can also investigate financial records, but this is much harder.

Comment: None of this I would recommend an ordinary faculty member undertaking in a non-official manner. Even if undertaken in an official manner, this would probably not be within the rules.

Comment: @IanSudbery Edited.  If you think there are rules that prevent law enforcement from doing this, let me know.  Certainly ordinary faculty cannot do step 2 unofficially.

Comment: By "official manner" I was more thiking about university authorities, rather than law enforcement. When it comes to the police, I suspect they just wouldn't have time for such a minor thing. The integrity of the academy might be very  important for us, but I suspect the police have other things to worry about.

Comment: Surely step 3 would have to be "encourage the suspect to ask for a bribe", rather than "offer a bribe", otherwise it would constitute entrapment that would render the evidence gathered inadmissible.

Comment: How would you get law enforcement to do this? If I'd go to the local police and told them this plan, they would laugh at me and say they have more infortant things to do.

Comment: @DanielHatton I knew I'd get that comment.  I don't believe you.

Comment: @user111388 You're right.

Comment: Thanks for the challenge, @AnonymousPhysicist.  After a bit of digging, I'm confident that my previous comment is correct in countries party to the European Convention on Human Rights (Teixeira de Castro v. Portugal 1998), but not in Singapore (How Poh Sun v. PP 1991) and probably not in South Africa (Criminal Procedure Act 1977 as amended, section 252A).  I've been unable to obtain definite information for any other jurisdiction.

Comment: Interesting.  .....

Comment: @user111388 "If I'd go to the local police and told them this plan, they would laugh at me"  This is why some universities employ their own police or security staff.

Comment: Then please add to the question that this is about"university police". I am not familiar with the concept of university police (it's not worldwide) and thus would not have thought you mean university police by "law enforcement". Still, it's hard for me to believe you can just go to this police, tell them your plan and then they just go along with this. It seems also unlikely that a "normal" student would try to offer a bribe just to help this investigation. If you have any experience etc. that uni policy indeed works in this way, please add it to the answer.

Comment: @user111388 This is about law enforcement investigation rather than university policy.  There's no need for a student to be involved.  It does not have to be university police.  I didn't claim that police would do this on request.  The question was "how can something like this be investigated" not "what can I, as a student, do to investigate".  Law enforcement sting operations like this are often featured in the news in the United States.

Comment: It makes sense for an operation like this to catch a drug dealer, but has there ever been such an operation to catch a professor who writes thesis' for their students? I find it hard to tell now if this is an "academic answer" (as in "if the government had infinitely money and personel, they would do this") or is it a real-world answer? And, what is the recommendation to the OP? Should they go to police? Or to university police, if any?

Comment: @user111388 Neither the question nor the answer really have anything to do with academia; it's all about bribery.  The question didn't ask if investigating was a good idea; I'd say a student should spend their time studying.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Am I right in thinking, though, that "university police" in the US are really just state police officers who happen to be based on the university campus, rather than actual university-appointed and university-controlled police like the [University Constables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_University_Constabulary) in their 19th-century heyday?

Comment: @DanielHatton Each university has its own practices, but in some cases they work directly for the university, even if it is a private university.

Comment: I don’t know if the investigative strategy described in this answer is feasible, but +1 for emphasizing that the alleged behavior described in the question is likely criminal. I find it strange that this can be regarded as controversial.